# Learning SDL in C

Tags: c, sdl

I know the basics of C and I'm looking into SDL. What I need at this point are some tutorials, documentation or perhaps a book about using the SDL libraries in C, especially about graphics.

The problem is that every online resource that I have found deals with C++, where I am looking for resources in C.

I have looked at gpwiki.org, which had an entire section on C but mingw won't compile it because some of the includes are C++ libraries (I only installed the C compiler). Other sources like sol.gfxile.net/gp/ say that they are a C tutorial, but "use C++ for its conveniently loosened variable placement rules.". Most of the tutorials on the SDL site itself are based in C++.

Does anyone know of a good learning resource in C for SDL programming?

Answer (score 27):

Have a look at [this tutorial series](http://www.parallelrealities.co.uk/2011/09/basic-game-tutorial-1-opening-window.html) at Parallel Realities. It covers SDL with C.

Comment: Looks promising, thanks a lot!

Comment: The link seems dead. Luckily, the tutorials seem still alive [over here](http://www.parallelrealities.co.uk/2011/09/basic-game-tutorial-1-opening-window.html)

Comment: @Ancurio both the links are now dead. Do you have new ones?

Comment: @Keatinge the old page is still available through waybackmachine, however I would strongly advice against using it due to being for SDL1.2; SDL2 changed quite a bit of the API. Most of the code [here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php) should be independent of C++

Comment: updated link for these tutorials - https://www.parallelrealities.co.uk/tutorials/ (they note that they're out of date)

Comment: https://www.parallelrealities.co.uk/tutorials/shooter/shooter1.php